# Rails dynamically add styling to tr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an normal table. Now i would like to style an `tr-tag` depending on data. But see it youself how i imagine it:

```
<% @patients.each do |patient| %>
 <tr <%= "style='color:red'" if patient.thisyear < Date.today %> >
  <td><%= patient.vorname %></td>
  <td><%= patient.nachname %></td>
  <td><%= patient.birthday.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") %></td>
  <td><%= patient.year %> Jahre</td>
  <td><%= (patient.thisyear-Date.today).to_i %> Tagen</td>
</tr>
```

But somehow this is not working:

```
<tr <%= "style='color:red'" if patient.thisyear < Date.today %> >
```

What would you recomment my to style the `tr-tag`? Thanks

Comment: What error do you have or what do you expect but haven't happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the way adding `class` attribute instead of `style` like this:

```
<tr class="<%= (patient.thisyear < Date.today) ? 'red' : 'not_red' %>">
```

and to your CSS file:

```
tr.red {
  color: red;
}
```